# Unable to query SQL server 2008 databse from linux?

Tags: linux, spring, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I have written a JAVA SPRING RESTFUL web-service to query SQL server 2008 database using sqljdbc4 driver. It works fine from windows machine, but when I deploy the code to a Linux box I am not be to execute both select and insert queries.

I tried using “SET NOCOUNT ON”, but no luck.

**Error while executing select query**
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [ Select statement ………. );]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The statement did not return a result set.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

**Error while executing insert query**
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [Insert into log(id, datetime)  values(?,?)]; SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.

**JDBC driver POM dependency.**
            com.microsoft.sqlserver
            sqljdbc4
            4.0

I tried some other stuff that I read on google but no luck. If some can point me to a right direction, I would really appreciate help.

Comment: You should look deeper in your stack traces. It says "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed". But why it was closed? The answer should come after that in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Try using jtds driver instead of microsoft jdbc driver.

Comment: I had a similar issue: sqljdbc4 worked on Windows, but not on Linux, the executeQuery() statement never returned (not even an exception).  Tried jtds and it now works for both environments.